# iOS - UIScrollView inside UICollectionViewCell - animation is not correct (delayed) for inner view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I have this hierarchy:

`UICollectionView - UICollectionViewCell - UIScrollView - UIView: DetailedView`

Inside UIView, I have detailed content (buttons, images views etc). UICollectionView has height constraint.

Inside button click, I have an animation to smoothly change height with this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
           self.heightConstraint.constant = newHeight
           self.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()


           self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: { finished in })
```

Animation of `UICollectionView` is correct, but `DetailedView` animation is weird. It is looking like items are stretched and their size is corrected with a delay.

I have 4 cells in UICollectionView, if I scroll to sides.

If I dont call `self.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()`, content (DetailedView) is repeated inside `UICollectionView` and there is no animation for the content at all. It just "sits" at its place and repeats.

[image]

(now those are 2 of my 4 cells inside one view, but they should be each on its own "page")

But it should be

[image]

My scene has these constraints (I have removed button that starts animation, it had no constraint and was put in top left corner):

[image]

`Height Constraint` is changed inside animation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide more code. But two things first to start with which you should take into account:

Animations and `.layoutIfNeeded()` are intensive methods to call, anywhere in an app. They usually completetely re-calculates constraints, sizing, positionning etc. You also need to bear in mind, the more `subviews` present in the view you are calling it on, the heavier the task. In your case, you are calling it on the lowest views in the hierarchy, then moving up to their `superViews` to call it again, and then you call it a third time on the highest view of the hierarchy..

So You're doing the work three times for each sub-subview (in this case `DetailedView`), twice for your middle subviews (your `scrollView`), and once for your view which contains your `UICollectionView`.
So just by assumption, you're doing too much layout-resizing here, all the while trying to animating it all, which might explain why your collectionView's animation is fine (calculated only once), but that it's cell's subviews are not (they are being re-calculated more than once, and not at the same time as the `collectionView`'s)

You need to figure out which view is needed for re-sizing and Usually, you should only have to call `.layoutIfNeeded()` on a particular view to animate whatever it is you need. By this definition, you need to test your hierarchy for the right place to call `.layoutIfNeeded()` when you're re-sizing many of it's subviews which themselves are getting constraint changes. While animating a higher-level view in the hierarchy does means you re-calculate all of the subviews too, the animation methods for UIView should take care of ironing out the transitions for them as well if you change their constraints prior to calling the `.layoutIfNeeded()`.

Unfortunately, as your hierarchy grows in complexity, it does become more and more challenging, so trial and error is sometimes the safe route to go.

Second, it's nearly impossible to judge how appropriate your approach is to your use case without more code. This is especially the case if you're adding a scrollview inside of a collectionView which is itself a UIScrollView subclass. So there might also be some touch interaction/animation conflicting against your desired animation. I won't correct your code otherwise, because i don't know what you're trying to do, but start by figuring out which view should perform `.layoutIfNeeded()`.

For now, check out these videos by google, they go into this hierarchy `.layoutIfNeeded()` issue really well:

[Animating Constraints Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZLPg2InQ44U&index=9&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIKGQekfmV0Qk52qLG5LU2jO)

[Animating Constraints Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVlNl4JDzL4&index=8&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIKGQekfmV0Qk52qLG5LU2jO)

Comment: @murpguy I have added some details about constraints and behavior

Comment: Looking at your constraints, you have a height constraint mixed with both topAnchor and bottomAnchor, along with a width constraint mixed with leading and trailingAnchor. Like before, you're kind of setting two sets of contraints for the same thing. Usually, either leading+trailing, or either of those + a width constraint should be used. So try removing some constraints here (i usually try to avoid width and height constraints, and stick to leading/top/bottom/trailing for container views inside cells). Also for your code, could you paste the code you use to resize?